# Why can any positive martingale be written as the exponential of an Ito integral w.r.t. Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Why is any positive martingale the exponential of an Ito integral w.r.t. Brownian motion?

Here is a little proof.

> For any positive P-martingale M, $dM_t = Mt ·1/M_tdM_t$. By Martingale Representation Theorem, $dMt = \Gamma_tdW(t)$ for some adapted process $\Gamma_t$. So $dM_t = M_t(\Gamma_t/M_t)dW$, i.e. any positive
>   martingale must be the exponential of an integral w.r.t. Brownian motion.

Where in this proof are we using the fact that $M$ is positive?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the fact that $M$ is positive because you divide by $M$.

Dividing by zero is the root of evil.

Comment: So, $M_t$ can be a negative Martingale?

Comment: Replace $M $ by  $-M $

Comment: Dividing by zero ,  is not sufficient

Comment: I do not understand your remark.

Comment: Your Answer :Dividing by zero is the root of evil. It is not sufficient.

Comment: If M is negative, it is certainly not an exponential of a b.m. where does the proof fail in that case?

Comment: $dM_t=M_tdB_t $ and $M_0=-1$. You can solve it.

Comment: @Berouz : answer is sufficient indeed.

Comment: Everything lies in the in the sign of the initial condition indeed.